# HTTPS Causes Broken Back Links?

Tags: seo, https, 404

If I change my URL to force `https` does this effect all of my backlinks to be broken and to be lost one by one? And if so if I change it back will it will this restore the back links on the site? Any advice for this is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you change your site over to `https`, you will want to 301 redirect your `http` site to your new `https` site.  This will preserve your backlinks both for visitors that click on them and for search engines that use them to assign authority to your site.

Comment: And after you've done that, ask those who backlink and are aproachable to change it to https :)